# FPDF-Merge Error()

Tags: php, forms, pdf, fpdf, fill

Im using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php) script fill forms

To fill PDF forms using a PHP array. Everything works fine with the template PDF, but when I make a custom template 'fillable' and try to fill it I get the following error.

```
FPDF-Merge Error: startxref tag expected, read 0000000843 00000 n
```

I have no clue what this means and I cannot find anything on "startxref" on Google. Please help.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Here is my template pdf. I added forms to it using acrobat 8 Pro Mac
http://devinblackwell.info/files/documents/flag-app.pdf

Comment: You should keep for yourself what you tried. I will check my magic crystal globe to view your template.

Comment: If you search for `[php] startxref` then there are 12 results. Have you looked through them? (http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D%20startxref )

Comment: Welcome to SO!  As a general rule, it is **always** as good idea to either post your code, what you have tried or show the research you have already done.  We don't make it a rule to do your work for you here, but are more than happy to help you find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

And I WIN !

I finally chose to forget FPDF and directly make my own system, which is simply what FPDF do I think.
Don't worry that isn't difficult at all.

Have a look on this website, just understand how work fdf to fill pdf template (mapping) and.. do it :)

http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/pdftk

STEP 1 : Create a FDF content in PhP

```
/* A FDF content empy */
$xfdf_head = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xfdf xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/xfdf/" xml:space="preserve"><fields>';
$xml_data = '';
$xfdf_end = '</fields></xfdf>';

/* Generate all fields with field_key form webform and value form submission */
foreach ($webform['#node']->webform['components'] as $key => $value) {

    if ($webform['#submission']->data[$key]['value'][0]){
        $valeur = $webform['#submission']->data[$key]['value'][0];
    } else {
        $valeur = '';
    }

    $xml_data .= '
        <field name="'.$webform['#node']->webform['components'][$key]['form_key'].'">
            <value>'.$valeur.'</value>
        </field>';
}


$FDF_content = $xfdf_head.$xml_data.$xfdf_end;
```

STEP 2 : Create a FDF FILE and write your content in it

```
$FDF_file = fopen('new_fdf.fdf', 'w');
fwrite($FDF_file, $FDF_content);
fclose($FDF_file);
```

STEP 3 : Use PDFTK command in Php (check website upside) [fill these 2 var before..]

```
$pdftk_command = '/usr/bin/pdftk '. $pdf_template .' fill_form new_fdf.fdf output '.$new_fillup_pdf;
shell_exec($pdftk_command);
```

STEP 4 : Force download or Open the new PDF in PHP. (I let you find how, that's easy)